# Удалить ребра графа

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю мини игру на wpf
[image]

Есть проблема - не знаю как привязать ребра к вершинам графа. Т.е. если сейчас синий игрок нажмёт на красную вершину, то нужно, чтобы красные ребра к этой (уже синей) вершине разрывались

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущий код выглядит так:

```
private void Btn_Lines(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point btn1Point = ((Button)sender).TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(-25, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            if (((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top <= 300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left <= 300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top >= -300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left >= -300 &&
                buttons[i].Foreground == ((Button)sender).Foreground)
            {
                Line l = new Line();

                if (buttons[i].Foreground.ToString() == "#FFFF0000")
                {
                    l.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
                else if (buttons[i].Foreground.ToString() == "#FF0000FF")
                {
                    l.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                }
                l.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
                Point btn2Point = buttons[i].TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(25, 0));
                l.X1 = btn1Point.X + ((Button)sender).ActualWidth;
                l.X2 = btn2Point.X;
                l.Y1 = btn1Point.Y + ((Button)sender).ActualHeight / 2;
                l.Y2 = btn2Point.Y + buttons[i].ActualHeight / 2;
                main.Children.Add(l);
            }
        }
    }
```

Пытался добавить `Dictionary<int, List<Line>>`, где int - номер кнопки, а List - его вершины (до 6 на каждую вершину, т.к. в одной строке вершины не связываются), но получил ошибку. Да и думаю, что дальше не разберусь.
В общем проблема заключается в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы при захвате чужой вершины, ее ребра разрывались?

**Хотел сделать так, но ошибка...**

```
public static Dictionary<int, List<Line>> chains = new Dictionary<int, List<Line>>(6);
        private void Btn_Lines(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Point btn1Point = ((Button)sender).TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(-25, 0));
            List<Line> ll = new List<Line>(6);

            for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
                {
                    if (((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top <= 300 &&
                    ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left <= 300 &&
                    ((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top >= -300 &&
                    ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left >= -300)
                    {
                        Line l = new Line();
                        l.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

                        l.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
                        Point btn2Point = buttons[i].TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(25, 0));
                        l.X1 = btn1Point.X + ((Button)sender).ActualWidth;
                        l.X2 = btn2Point.X;
                        l.Y1 = btn1Point.Y + ((Button)sender).ActualHeight / 2;
                        l.Y2 = btn2Point.Y + buttons[i].ActualHeight / 2;

                        ll.Add(l);
                    }
                }
                chains.Add(i, ll);
            }



            for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                if (buttons[i].Foreground == ((Button)sender).Foreground)
                {
                    foreach (List<Line> p in chains.Values)
                        foreach(Line l in p)
                            main.Children.Add(l);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделал все как и хотел. Не знаю насколько это ужасно выглядит. Если кто-то может подсказать правильное решение, буду очень благодарен

```
private static List<Line> ch = new List<Line>();

    private void Btn_Lines(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int peak_chains = 0;   
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        {
            if (((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top <= 300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left <= 300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Top - buttons[i].Margin.Top >= -300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Margin.Left - buttons[i].Margin.Left >= -300 &&
                ((Button)sender).Foreground == buttons[i].Foreground)
            {
                Line l = new Line();
                Point btn1Point = ((Button)sender).TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(-25, 0));
                Point btn2Point = buttons[i].TransformToAncestor(main).Transform(new Point(25, 0));


                l.StrokeThickness = 2.0;
                l.X1 = btn1Point.X + ((Button)sender).ActualWidth;
                l.X2 = btn2Point.X;
                l.Y1 = btn1Point.Y + ((Button)sender).ActualHeight / 2;
                l.Y2 = btn2Point.Y + buttons[i].ActualHeight / 2;
                ch.Add(l);
                l.Stroke = ((Button)sender).Foreground;
                peak_chains++;
                main.Children.Add(l);

                if (((Button)sender).Foreground == Brushes.Red)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < ch.Count; z++)
                    {
                        if (((l.X1 == ch[z].X1 && l.Y1 == ch[z].Y1) ||
                            (l.X2 == ch[z].X2 && l.Y2 == ch[z].Y2))
                            && ch[z].Stroke != Brushes.Red)
                        {
                            main.Children.Remove(ch[z]);
                            ch.RemoveAt(z);
                            z = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if (((Button)sender).Foreground == Brushes.Blue)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < ch.Count; z++)
                    {
                        if (((l.X1 == ch[z].X1 && l.Y1 == ch[z].Y1) ||
                            (l.X2 == ch[z].X2 && l.Y2 == ch[z].Y2)) 
                            && ch[z].Stroke != Brushes.Blue)
                        {
                            main.Children.Remove(ch[z]);
                            ch.RemoveAt(z);
                            z = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        if(peak_chains > 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((peak_chains - 1).ToString());
        }
    }
```